# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

Need help with the exception getting whilst posting data to server, although GET method works fine within the same REST Resource. Code is given below; Early attention appreciated.

REST Endpoint

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/trading-api")
public class MemberMessageResource {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemberMessageResource.class);

@Inject
MemberMessageService service;   

@RequestMapping(value = "/messages/reply/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MemMessage> replyMemeberMessage(@RequestBody MemMessage msg)
        throws URISyntaxException {

    log.info("REST Request to reply a message : {" + msg.toString() + " }");

        MemMessage result = msg;        

        return new ResponseEntity<MemMessage>(result, HttpStatus.OK);   
    }
}
```

MessageService.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('nkApp').factory(
    'messagesService',
    [
    '$http',
    '$q',

    function($http, $q) {

        var REST_SERVICE_URI = '/trading-api/messages/';

        var factory = {         
        replyMemeberMessage : replyMemeberMessage           
        };

        return factory;        

        function replyMemeberMessage(message) {
        console.log('Replying Message : ', message);
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post(REST_SERVICE_URI + "reply/" + message)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while Replying Message');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        }       
    } ]);
```

Console Error

```
2017-03-10 23:49:21.515  WARN 11764 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Browser Error

```
{"timestamp":1489189761519,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/trading-api/messages/reply/[object%20Object]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your message object should not be part of your url, it should be your request body. Instead of adding to the url string, just pass it as the data argument in your angular javascript function:

`$http.post(REST_SERVICE_URI + "reply/", message)`